# NSUserDefaults preferences that don't sync in iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, nsuserdefaults, preferences

It's difficult to find explicit info on this.

Let's say I have something stored in NSUserDefaults and I **do not** want it to sync with iTunes.  Should it be stored in the keychain instead?  Does the keychain sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing with the device keychain (whose elements don't get deleted on app removal) you can simply use an `NSMutableDictionary` and mix it with `initWithContentsOfFile:`, `writeToFile:atomically:` and the `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`, this way you would have exactly the same structure of the NSUserDefaults (that is no other that a `NSMutableDictionary` at its heart) and you have control over if it should backed up or not. Mind that @rmaddy suggestion of putting it in the cache directory means that, if the device needs memory, your file would be wiped.

EDIT: Sorry probably I misread, the `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` is to not have it synced from iCloud not iTunes. If you simply want to not be syncd with iTunes you can set the `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `NO` in your app's plist

EDIT2: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) (section Where You Should Put Your App’s Files) the kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey will exclude it to be backed up by iTunes too.